# Django Race Condition

Tags: django, postgresql, race-condition

What is the best way to avoid race conditions with Django ORM? I am using Postgres database. Here is a simplified version of the code which is vulnerable to race conditions (rare but can happen):

```
last_account_balance = AccountBalance.objects.filter(
    account_id=account_id
).last()

new_account_balance = AccountBalance(
    account_id=account_id,
    balance= last_account_balance.balance + 100
)

new_account_balance.save()
```

What if two separate processed execute the code above at the same time?

Let's say the last entry in the database with account_id 123 has balance of 100.

First process will insert a new entry with balance increased by 100, that is 200.

Second process will insert a new entry with balance increased by 100, that is 200 as well.

But it should increase from 200 to 300 as another process inserted a new row in the meantime.

Comment: Same way you deal with it in regular PostgreSQL, when not wrangling an ORM: Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, and/or optimistic concurrency control.

Comment: @CraigRinger But I am not updating a row in the database. I am inserting a new row to the database and its field value is dependent on a previous row. The problem is a new row can be inserted in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that what you are describing is a very good approach to your problem. What I'd do instead is that I'd create a `Deposit` Model which would have a `ForeignKey` to the account and save the date of the deposit and the amount that was deposited (and probably other information needed).

Now, I'd just add a new `Deposit` and then I could get the Balance of the account each time just by summing all the related `Deposit`s (and similarly subtracting `Withdrawal`s).

Of course there could be other usage cases that would actually need *table locking* to be sure that rows in a table do not change between SQL statements, however these are database specific and not really related to django. For completeness, I've found a very nice introduction to postgresql table locking here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html -- the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` table-level lock seems to be what'd solve your problem (however I'd double think my design before using things that could lead to deadlocks).

Comment: This answer is definitely the way to go. Having a `Transaction` model or similar that stores deposit/withdrawals for an account and having a separate process that runs through the transactions in the db at a later stage and executes them is (very) basically the model that banks etc use now.